# Yodlee Token authentication failed for cobrand/user Stale conversation credentials</errorDetail>

Tags: yodlee

I sometime get this error while trying to add Accounts(v1.0/jsonsdk/SiteAccountManagement/addSiteAccount1) or get MFA Response(v1.0/jsonsdk/Refresh/getMFAResponseForSite)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <Errors xmlns="http://namespace.yodlee.com/pfm/2009/Error">
    <Error>
      <errorDetail>Token authentication failed for cobrand/user Stale conversation credentials</errorDetail>
  </Error>
</Errors>
```

can someone help me that issue.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yodlee doesn't allow multiple user login and hence this exception comes when you have logged in the user again by calling the Login(/authenticate/login​) API and still using the old userSessionToken.

Please use the login (/authenticate/login​) call once and use the same userSessionToken for all the API calls for next 25-30 minutes.